# Dynamic Module data not showing up in the administration panel of sitefinity

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-10

I've got a dynamic module that I created with some data that gets imported from an import tool I've created.  Now I keep the config information for these modules stored under /app_data/Sitefinity and check them into our tfs version control system and everything works great under our local and dev environments.  But we had an issue on QA where the build didn't import the module correctly and to fix this I eventually had to delete the module on QA and imported it back in from the config we had on dev.  So now the dynamic module works great from our administration module and we can manually create the data there fine.

The issue now is that when I run my import tool, it acts and runs fine against our QA site, but when we go to look into the data on the administration panel it doesn't show up on the site.  I've also checked the table in sql server and the imported data is in there.  Also I've made sure that the data is published and set to visible, so I'm not sure why the data isn't showing up in the administration section.  Anybody have any ideas??

Here's the code:

```
// Set the culture name for the multilingual fields
                var cultureName = "en";
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(cultureName);

                Type locationType =
                    TypeResolutionService.ResolveType("Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.Locations.Location");
                DynamicContent location = null;

                DynamicModuleManager dynamicModuleManager = DynamicModuleManager.GetManager("dynamicProvider2");
                dynamicModuleManager.Provider.SuppressSecurityChecks = true;


                location = dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItems(locationType)
                    .FirstOrDefault(
                        x =>
                            x.GetValue<string>("OperationId") == importLocation.OperationId.ToString() &&
                            x.Status == ContentLifecycleStatus.Master && x.Visible == true);

                if (location == null && importLocation.IsActive)
                {
                    // We have a new location.
                    DynamicContent locationItem = dynamicModuleManager.CreateDataItem(locationType);

                    locationItem.SetString("Title", importLocation.Title, cultureName);
                    locationItem.SetString("Description", importLocation.Description, cultureName);
                    locationItem.SetString("OperationId", importLocation.OperationId.ToString(), cultureName);

                    Address address = new Address();
                    CountryElement addressCountry =
                        Config.Get<LocationsConfig>().Countries.Values.First(x => x.Name == "United States");
                    address.CountryCode = addressCountry.IsoCode;
                    address.StateCode = importLocation.State;
                    address.City = importLocation.City;
                    address.Street = importLocation.Street;
                    address.Zip = importLocation.Zip;

                    address.Latitude = importLocation.Latitude;
                    address.Longitude = importLocation.Longitude;
                    address.MapZoomLevel = 8;
                    locationItem.SetValue("Address", address);
                    locationItem.Visible = true;

                    TaxonomyManager taxonomyManager = TaxonomyManager.GetManager();
                    taxonomyManager.Provider.SuppressSecurityChecks = true;
                    var foundRootServiceArea = taxonomyManager.GetTaxonomies<HierarchicalTaxonomy>()
                            .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "Service-Areas");
                    foreach (var serviceArea in importLocation.ServiceAreas)
                    {
                        var foundServiceArea =
                            foundRootServiceArea.Taxa.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Name == serviceArea);
                        if (foundServiceArea != null)
                        {
                            locationItem.Organizer.AddTaxa("ServiceAreas", foundServiceArea.Id);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var newServiceArea = taxonomyManager.CreateTaxon<HierarchicalTaxon>();
                            newServiceArea.Title = serviceArea;
                            newServiceArea.Name = serviceArea;
                            foundRootServiceArea.Taxa.Add(newServiceArea);

                            locationItem.Organizer.AddTaxa("ServiceAreas", newServiceArea.Id);
                        }

                    }

                    locationItem.SetValue("PublicationDate", DateTime.UtcNow);

                    // Modified to publish instead of set items as draft
                    locationItem.SetWorkflowStatus(dynamicModuleManager.Provider.ApplicationName, "Published",
                        new CultureInfo(cultureName));

                    // You need to call SaveChanges() in order for the items to be actually persisted to data store
                    dynamicModuleManager.SaveChanges();

                    // Use lifTecycle so that LanguageData and other Multilingual related values are correctly created
                    DynamicContent checkOutLocationItem =
                        dynamicModuleManager.Lifecycle.CheckOut(locationItem) as DynamicContent;
                    dynamicModuleManager.Lifecycle.CheckIn(checkOutLocationItem);
                    dynamicModuleManager.SaveChanges();

                    return Ok();
                }
                else if (location != null)
                {
                    // Check to see if we need to update each field.
                    if (location.DoesFieldExist("Title") && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(location.GetValue("Title").ToString()))
                    {
                        if (location.GetValue("Title").ToString() != importLocation.Title)
                        {
                            location.SetString("Title", importLocation.Title);
                        }
                    }

                    if (location.DoesFieldExist("Description") &&
                        !String.IsNullOrEmpty(location.GetValue("Description").ToString()))
                    {
                        if (location.GetValue("Description").ToString() != importLocation.Description)
                        {
                            location.SetString("Description", importLocation.Description);
                        }
                    }

                    if (location.DoesFieldExist("Address"))
                    {
                        var address = location.GetValue<Address>("Address");
                        if (address.City != importLocation.City)
                        {
                            address.City = importLocation.City;
                        }
                        if (address.StateCode != importLocation.State)
                        {
                            address.StateCode = importLocation.State;
                        }
                        if (address.Street != importLocation.Street)
                        {
                            address.Street = importLocation.Street;
                        }
                        if (address.Zip != importLocation.Zip)
                        {
                            address.Zip = importLocation.Zip;
                        }
                        if (address.Latitude != importLocation.Latitude)
                        {
                            address.Latitude = importLocation.Latitude;
                        }
                        if (address.Longitude != importLocation.Longitude)
                        {
                            address.Longitude = importLocation.Longitude;
                        }

                        location.SetValue("Address", address);
                    }
                    location.Visible = importLocation.IsActive;

                    if (!importLocation.IsActive)
                    {
                        location.Status = ContentLifecycleStatus.Deleted;
                        dynamicModuleManager.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    else
                    {        
                        location.SetWorkflowStatus(
                             dynamicModuleManager.Provider.ApplicationName, 
                             "Published", new CultureInfo(cultureName));

                        dynamicModuleManager.SaveChanges();

                        DynamicContent checkOutLocationItem =
                            dynamicModuleManager.Lifecycle.CheckOut(location) as 
                            DynamicContent;

 dynamicModuleManager.Lifecycle.CheckIn(checkOutLocationItem);
                        dynamicModuleManager.SaveChanges();
                    }

                    return Ok();
                }
```

Comment: Is the MultiSite module activated? If so, you need to make sure you configured the dynamic module to show on that site and use the proper provider name during the import process. 
If not, it might be worthwhile to share some of your import code

Comment: Thanks for responding. I do have the multisite module activated and I've selected my module to work with the site.  I added the import code above.  I've got the provider set up in the admin as well, but I do have one question for one of the provider's parameters applicationName I've got it set to dynamicProvider2.  Should that be the sitename??

Comment: no, not necessarily the site name. dynamicProvider2 is generated by Sitefinity, so better leave it as is. So, I assume your problem is solved then?

Comment: I'll try changing that applicationName and see what happens, I've tried everything else at this point. I'll post back here as soon as I try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve the provider dynamically for the current site based on the module name, I have created this helper method.

```
public static DynamicModuleManager GetDynamicProvider(string moduleName)
        {
            // Set the provider name for the DynamicModuleManager here. All available providers are listed in
            // Administration -> Settings -> Advanced -> DynamicModules -> Providers                

            var provider = SystemManager.CurrentContext.CurrentSite.GetDefaultProvider(moduleName);

            var providerName = (provider != null) ? provider.ProviderName : DynamicModuleManager.GetDefaultProviderName();

            return DynamicModuleManager.GetManager(providerName);
        }
```

Comment: I'm still not sure how the dynamic provider got out of whack during configuration, but this totally worked.  Thanks, Amit.